# Does OneLogin SAML Authn Request Signature Validation Tool Support HTTP-POST Binding?

Tags: saml, onelogin

I am talking about https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php . In our case, we use embedded signature value in Authn request xml. Looks like it doesn't work as our ProtocolBinding is **HTTP-POST**.
For example lets take this sample xml,

```
    <samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="pfx41d8ef22-e612-8c50-9960-1b16f15741b3" Version="2.0" ProviderName="SP test" IssueInstant="2014-07-16T23:52:45Z" Destination="http://idp.example.com/SSOService.php" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs">
  <saml:Issuer>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#pfx41d8ef22-e612-8c50-9960-1b16f15741b3">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>yJN6cXUwQxTmMEsPesBP2NkqYFI=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>g5eM9yPnKsmmE/Kh2qS7nfK8HoF6yHrAdNQxh70kh8pRI4KaNbYNOL9sF8F57Yd+jO6iNga8nnbwhbATKGXIZOJJSugXGAMRyZsj/rqngwTJk5KmujbqouR1SLFsbo7Iuwze933EgefBbAE4JRI7V2aD9YgmB3socPqAi2Qf97E=</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"/>
  <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
  </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I am using **ds:SignatureValue** value that would go into ***Signature of the SAML AuthN Request*** box. Also I have mentioned proper cert in **"X.509 cert of the Service Provider"**. But it always returns **"Signature validation failed. AuthN Request rejected"**. I can see **"Paste the AuthN Request if you want to also validate its signature (HTTP-Redirect binding)"** mentioned in the page.

So I am wondering if this validation tool only works for HTTP-Redirect binding & not for HTTP-POST binding. Otherwise, we will have to check from our side & we don't see any issues as of now.

Comment: Are you pasting the request into the tool as sent/received? Or are you pasting it pretty-printed?

Comment: Not pretty printed, pasting it as it is sent

Comment: I don't have any issues with the validation tool when passing in a properly canonicalized and signed authnrequest... Which is not what you're showing above (which is their sample signed request). That sample is certainly not canonicalized with http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#.

Comment: @Andrew K did you use HTTP-POST binging? ... I used canonicalized only...sample is just to show what fields I am using

Comment: Yes. I generated an AuthnRequest with my test SP using POST. I put its public key in the x.509 field, my entity ID and the destination of the AuthnRequest at the IdP, and told it to ignore time issues. Worked fine.